# Adding a jquery timepicker into a modal that was creates by angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

[Repository for Project](https://github.com/mwithington/ClockPicker-with-Modal)

here is the repository to see what i have done so far. I got the clock and modal to combine nicely however the popup for the modal seems to be layered behind the modal itself. I know that jquery and angular don't play nice together. However i have gotten an older version of this to work with a modal however i need to use the newest version because the callbacks have information that i need. If anyone has suggestions i would really appreciate it! Thankyou!

Here are some code snip its from the repository

index.html inside the folder specified clockpicker-gh-pages:

```
   <html>
<head>
<title>ClockPicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/github.min.css">


</head>
<body ng-app="mymodal">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
        <button ng-click="toggleModal('Success')" class="btn btn-default">Success</button>
        <button ng-click="toggleModal('Remove')" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button>
        <button ng-click="toggleModal('Deny')" class="btn btn-default">Deny</button>
        <button ng-click="toggleModal('Cancel')" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        <modal visible="showModal">

                    <div class="input-group clockpicker">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="09:30">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                        </span>


                    </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" class="ng-scope">$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();</script>
        </modal>

            </div>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and from this folder there is a modal app.js script that contains:

```
    var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.buttonClicked = "";
    $scope.toggleModal = function (btnClicked) {
        $scope.buttonClicked = btnClicked;
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
});

mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'userOptionsModal.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function (value) {
                if (value == true)
                    $(element).modal('show');
                else
                    $(element).modal('hide');
            });

            $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                });
            });

            $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

also to format the modal window the html file that is specified as User options modal is the template for the modal window.

```
<div class="modal fade">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ buttonClicked }} Hello world!</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" ng-transclude>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

please keep in mind most of the code that is listed here is within the folder labeled clockpicker-gh-pages. If this helps let me know!

Answer (score 0):

In angular's [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) documentation, it says the element passed into the link function for a directive is a "jqLite-wrapped element".

So in your example, it appears to me that the line of code `$(element).on( ... )` should be `element.on( ... )`.

EDIT: I didn't see the `$(element).modal( ... )` lines.  Though I've never used `modal` before I believe that should be modified in the same way.

The other option would be to put an id on your angular directive template, and access it like this.

`$('#myelementid').modal( ... )` and `$('#myelementid').on( ... )`